# Using SCIM, can my app ask the IdP whether the user is part of a group?

Tags: scim

The usual use of SCIM seems to be that user information (provisioning) can flow from the IdP to the app (aka, service provider).  But what if the app has a question for the IdP, like: "what is the group membership of this user?"  I don't see anything in SCIM to prevent that, but maybe I am missing something , maybe the IdP won't typically be listening for a query like that through SCIM, or maybe the SCIM server/gateway implementations readily available don't support it.  To implement single sign-on, wouldn't the app ask the IdP for whether a user is authenticated -- maybe that would be a similar flow to what I am asking?

Answer (score 0):

There are two distinct roles in SCIM - "client" and "service provider". The client makes RESTful requests to the SCIM API hosted by the service provider. The example you've given would require that both parties (IdP + App) had implemented the ability to handle both client and service provider roles, so that both can make requests to each other. IdPs almost universally will have SCIM clients implemented, but the IdP having a SCIM service provider implemented isn't as sure of a thing - this will depend on the specific IdP you are working with.